# How do I nest polymer layouts to fill complete page?

Tags: polymer, flexbox

I am trying to use polymer layouts in polymer elements, but I am unable to determine how they are supposed to be nested correctly.

I use body on `fullbleed` - this works correctly (grey area in example).

Then I add a polymer element `my-element` (horizontal layout), and *inside that* another custom element `your-element` (vertical layout).

The middle row of `your-element` ("Beta Two") is set to `flex`.

**Expected:** "Beta Two" expands **vertically** to fill the whole remaining space

**Observed:** "Beta Two" gets height = 0 (verifiable in element inspector)

If the `flex` tag is removed then "Beta Two" appears with standard height.

If "Beta Two" gets a `style="min-height:100px"` then it is drawn with this min-height.

If "Beta Two" gets a `style="min-height:100%"` that has no effect.

Many other posts have suggested to use `:host {display: block}` styling, but this did not help here (see jsbin - unless I applied it on the wrong elements?).

What would be the correct way to achieve this result?

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cejizoboci/1/edit

This is what I expect the desired end result to look like: http://jsbin.com/nufemimida/1/edit

[image: Nested Layout with full-height element inside]

Comment: Added an example about the "expected" behavior. This example is not using polymer and works exactly as expected - i.e. the innermost element "Beta Two" fills to make the whole thing expand vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@itboy put me on the right track with his edit, thanks!

So the answer is to make sure that the layout attributes are on the parent element. One way to do this is to add it when the element is used (itboy's proposal), but actually it is also possible to add it on the element declaration, ie like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" layout horizontal noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      div {
        background: lightgreen;
        border: 1px dotted white;
      }
    </style>

      <div>Alpha</div>
        <your-element flex ></your-element>
      <div>Gamma</div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Or similar for the second element

```
<polymer-element name="your-element" layout vertical noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      div {
        background: lightgreen;
        border: 1px dotted white;
      }
      #beta2 {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>

      <div>Alpha Two</div>
      <div flex id="beta2">Beta Two(flex)</div>
      <div>Gamma Two</div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

This allows the elements to be called without having to give a layout attribute when they are called:

```
<body fullbleed layout vertical style="background:lightgrey;">
  <div style="background-color:tomato">Top Line</div>
  <my-element flex ></my-element>
  <div style="background-color:tomato">Bottom Line</div>
</body>
```

Caveat: Make sure that the complete chain of elements uses the `layout` attributes.

jsbin with this solution: http://jsbin.com/cavoqipani/1/edit?html,output

**Polymer 1.0 solution to the same problem**

http://jsbin.com/xaxadutoli/edit?html,output

It works by wrapping the `<body>`inside a custom element, otherwise you have to encapsulate the body in an extra `<div>`

Answer (score -1):

Hmm here is what you want: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/seleta/1/watch?html,output)

Comment: I want the whole thing to expand _vertically_ - if I remove the `flex` tag the "Beta Two" gets visible, but it is not expanded to fill the complete vertical space. Or did I misunderstand your answer? PS: Editing question to enhance the "vertical" part.

Comment: Flex expand element horizontally not vertically. Please make design in Photoshop or paint and share its link.

Comment: which element you want to  expand vertical?

Comment: Flex _does_ normally expand vertically as long as it is not nested: http://jsbin.com/vododusoto/1/edit?html,output